# SQL listing combinations in different columns only once

Tags: sql, unique

My DB looks as followed

```
**Customer      Order           Product**
cid(PK)         oid(PK)         pid(PK)
fname           cid(FK)         pname
lname           pid(FK)         pprice
```

Now I'm using a query to get the following results:

```
**fname     lname       oid     pname       pprice**
Bill        Gates       1111    Router      40,-
Bill        Gates       1112    Laptop      699,-
Steve       Jobs        1113    Tablet      1299,-
Steve       Jobs        1114    Watch       699,-
```

What I want however is to list the first and last name only once if the person has more then one orders. How would I be able to achieve this?

Example expected output:

```
**fname     lname       oid     pname       pprice**
Bill        Gates       1111    Router      40,-
                        1112    Laptop      699,-
Steve       Jobs        1113    Tablet      1299,-
                        1114    Watch       699,-
```

Comment: It`s not an sql task. Do it in your report or fill blank values to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved with `LAG` function.
`LAG` function returns value of a given column from previous row.
Then we can compare this value from previous row with value from current row.
We can use `CASE` statement to return value depending on result of this comparison.

Here is a query which gives desired result:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN lag(concat(cop.fname, cop.lname), 1, 0) OVER (order by cop.oid) = concat(cop.fname, cop.lname)  THEN null 
        ELSE cop.fname
    END AS fname, 
    CASE 
        WHEN lag(concat(cop.fname, cop.lname), 1, 0) OVER (order by cop.oid) = concat(cop.fname, cop.lname)  THEN null 
        ELSE cop.lname
    END AS lname,
    cop.oid, 
    cop.pname, 
    cop.pprice
FROM
    (SELECT c.fname, c.lname, o.oid, p.pname, p.pprice
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN myorder o on c.cid=o.cid
    LEFT JOIN product p on o.pid=p.pid) cop
```

It is not good idea to choose `ORDER` as a name for table because `ORDER` is keyword in `SQL`. So I choosed `MYORDER` as a name for table containing orders.
Above query works for `Oracle` database

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by fname, Lname Order By Oid) as RN in your query to number the lines. Then in your outer query or your next query if you dump the results to a temporary table use a case statement to set fname and lname to empty string whenever RN is not 1.

You need an additional column such as Customer No to order on so you would order by CustomerNo, RN, Lname, Fname